# Java performance

Tags: java, xml, performance, xsd

I'm worried about performance.
I need to compare two XML document and save difference into DB.
Some tags could have list another tags: Objects and usual Strings.
I have a problems with null: if one tag is null, but another isn't null - I must write into DB.
I came up with such a solution: each the lowest(the smallest tag) I check with ternary operator.

```
String kdtTradeMarkName = kdtCommodityDescriptionDetails == null ? null : kdtCommodityDescriptionDetails.getTradeMarkName();
String dtTradeMarkName = dtCommodityDescriptionDetails == null ? null : dtCommodityDescriptionDetails.getTradeMarkName();
```

There are a lot of similar tags. Can I do this way? I'm worried about additional checks in ternary. These inside tags "kdtCommodityDescriptionDetails" and "dtCommodityDescriptionDetails" create 7 additional checks. If I do this way in whole class it will be maybe 50-100 additional checks. But it's more readable and convenient. Or I should create `if(kdtCommodityDescriptionDetails != null).` And checks for one of this is null and etc.
If I do this way I'll create about 100 rows for this example.
There is big a powerful server at my job.
Should I worry about it?
I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions (ternary operator and check of null value with an if) are very fast compared to the time spend to load an xml and parse it.

So don't loose your time to improve the performances of this part of code.

Generally don't spend time on performances before be sure that you need it.